# Synchronize AD attributes with Dynamics 365 System Users

Tags: active-directory, synchronization, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have an online instance of Dynamics 365 v. 9.0 with its basic OOB configuration. I need to synchronize a set of attributes from my local Active Directory users to Dynamics 365 system users entity. For this purpose, there aren't any logon or identity requirements between AD and CRM. The only need is to sync specific attributes like *position* of the user in the organization hierarchy.

Can I accomplish that without developing code?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an app that runs from your local network, since it will probably be difficult to configure any sort of cloud-based solution like Microsoft Flow or Zapier to talk to your local AD.

I'd recommend using Data Sync Studio from Simego (http://www.simego.com) for a code-less solution. It is a Windows program that would run from your local desktop or Windows server. It can connect to AD and Dynamics Online.

If this is a one-time migration, the trial version would probably work for you. If it is an ongoing synchronization, they have a server product that will run your sync jobs on a schedule.

- Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with Simego in any way - I just like their product for things like this. :)

Comment: Thank you, @josh-painter. I'll take a look at it.